# Netbeans - fix imports on entire project

Tags: netbeans, ide

I'm using netbeans IDE 8.0. When I hit right click inside the editor, one option is **Fix imports**(CTRL + SHIFT + I). This option adds useful imports and removes unused imports. But **How can I use Fix Imports on entire project(not single file)**? Is there any way for doing that?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Right click on the project (or a package if you want), then choose "Inspect and Transform".

In the dialog box, choose "Organize Imports" , from browse choose imports --> then --> organize imports:

[image]

There is also an inspection named "Unused Imports"

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.

Comment: Tried didn't work. It didn't do anything noticeable and definitelly didn't add missing imports.

Comment: I tried it and it worked, but when doing it on  a EJB module it suggests to delete a whole classes that are used in a WEB. I tried to use `Inspect and Transform` on EJB and WEB at the same time, a dialog showed saying `No patterns found`!!

Comment: **Clarification:** I've noticed that using `Inspect and Transform` on two modules (EJB and WEB) at the same time worked when the project doesn't use Maven and **didn't** work (No patterns found) when I execute it on a Maven project, anuone can explain this??

Comment: this is not the same behavior as Ctl+Shift+I (fix imports). It just organizes and removes unused imports. It will not add imports automatically if they match only 1 potential package